# using LinQ without Lambda expressions to define condition on a List type property

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have the following LinQ expression which is working fine. However, I wonder if it is possible to write the same query without using Lambda Expressions and *Contains*. What would be another option? Since ***Roles*** is a list type, I could not figure out another way.

```
var users = (from p in _db.People
             where p.Roles.Select(r => r.RoleId).Contains(roleid)
             select p).ToList();
```

**UPDATE 1:**
I meant: Not using Lambda, Contains, Select, etc.
but using only select, join, from, where, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should generate the join you want...

```
var users =
(
   from p in _db.People
   from r in p.Roles
   where r.RoleId == roleid
   select p
).ToList();
```

Edit: If you do not have relationships defined please try this (not tested)...

```
var query = (from p in db.people
join r in db.roles on p.roleID equals r.roleID
where r.roleID = roleID
select p).ToList();
```

Comment: It will return the same `user` multiple times if their `Roles` contains identical `RoleId`.

Comment: it is not working, it just retrieves every user in the table even though the roleId does not match. I think this is because it makes every possible combinations between the rows in two tables.

Comment: @erkaner It **is** working with a problem. See my comment above

Comment: @JacobSeleznev In your comment you mentioned _if their Roles contains identical RoleId._, but, it lists users for the chosen Role even though the user is not in that role, which is known as **NOT** working in the literature :) So, with your approach, Role chosen does not matter, it will list every user in the database.

Comment: @erkaner I understand :). That means filter `where r.RoleId == roleid` doesn't work ? You can rewrite this answer using method chain          `_db.People.SelectMany(p => p.Roles, (p, r) => new {p, r})
                        .Where(@t => @t.r.RoleId == roleid)
                        .Select(@t => @t.p).ToList();`

Comment: @JacobSeleznev thanks for the options! I was looking for a solution without using SelectMany, Select, or Where. I updated the question.

Comment: I believe this query generates cleaner sql... using Any() may generate an "exists" or "in" query... depends on how smart linq is at optimizing the query.  The linq I posted should just give you a join and return users with the given role.

Comment: @sam thanks for the update. However, I do not have access to this `p.roleID` since every person can have many roles.

Comment: @erkaner - Yes I realize there are multiple roles per person.  Please try the query I posted and you will see it is testing each of the many roles for each person against the roleID parameter.

Comment: @Sam there is no such property,it is undefined `p.roleID`

Comment: @erkaner plz post your actual code.  The code I posted was an example.  You must have ID's on tables (classes) you want to join.

Answer (score 1):

Not without lambda expressions - that's how linq does most of its heavy lifting.

You can use `.Any(...)`

```
var users =
(
    from p in _db.People
    where p.Roles.Any(r => r.RoleId == roleid)
    select p
).ToList();
```

Comment: I think he's asking how to avoid using both a lambda *and* a contains. And by lambda I think he means where.

Comment: @CameronMacFarland - Thanks, I did find that part of the question a little confusing.